# Phone stuck in Safe Mode (Volume Keys not functioning)

Tags: adb, shell, safe-mode

Recently my Samsung Galaxy E7 entered into Safe Mode. My volume keys are non functional. Can someone please suggest a way to get out of Safe Mode using ADB.

Comment: Can't you use power button to simply reboot or maybe shutdown the device?

Comment: No sir ! Since the power key is probably shorted, it will reboot into safe mode again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved. The volume keys were internally shorted leading to infinite boot into safe mode. Repairing the keys worked out.